# Powermockito to mock Environment static methods

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, powermockito

I'm new to using `Powermockito` to mock static methods.  My first attempt is to mock calls on the `Environment` class.  I have a sample test that exemplifies my problem as shown in my test class below.  The test is failing, so I'm seeking some help.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Environment.class})
public class StorageUtilsTest {
    @Test
    @Config(sdk = 22)
    public void myTest() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Environment.class);
        File mockStorageDirectoryFile = Mockito.mock(File.class);
        PowerMockito.when(Environment.getExternalStorageState()).thenReturn(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
        PowerMockito.when(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)).thenReturn(mockStorageDirectoryFile)`;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to mock the static method call to `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` and it returns null giving an exception `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: Argument should be a mock, but is: class java.lang.Class.`  The static method call is returning null.  I understand that the method call is deprecated in `sdk=29`, so I've configured the test to run with `sdk=22`, and it still didn't work.  So in an attempt to understand what was going on, I added a call to the `getExternalStorageState` method as shown above.  I get a null return value on this method too.  My understanding is that this method should return something, but it also returns null.  I'm configuring the test for `sdk=22` since I'm setting a `targetSdkVersion 29` in my build.gradle.

I'm really confused as to why I can't mock the static methods on the Environment class.  Will someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Mocking static methods is almost always a sign of a design problem. Instead, you should have some `interface StorageManager` that is the focus of your interaction and that you can mock normally.

Comment: I agree with you.  sorry I wasn't clear.  The static method that I'm mocking is an Environment method, not my method.  My class uses the Environment method that I'm mocking.

Comment: I understand that. I'm saying that you should redesign your API so that it doesn't have a hidden dependency on `Environment` (e.g., you should pass the variables). This is in fact a serious deficiency in the Android API, but it's unfortunately baked in.

Comment: OK, aside from re-writing my API, and aside from the serious deficiency in the Android API can someone provide some feedback on what I'm doing wrong mocking a standard android class?